# How do I see part of EER diagram in mySQL workbench

Tags: reverse-engineering, mysql-workbench, data-modeling, diagram

I got a .mvb file from company, the relationship are complicated and Tables are a lot, I wonder how could I see the relationship between the tables piece by piece, to understand the relationship and database quickly.

Comment: Do you have access to the database at all? Or are you able to recreate the schema?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
 `Model-diagram Properties`
And then:
`Arrange -autolayout`

Comment: Oh, I knew that, it will auto give your the entire project layout.I mean is there a way to only see, lets say 5 tables relationship out of 50 tables total.